# how to order and group by count subquery from an ordered list on ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to do this on Ruby On Rails with Postgres PostGIS.

I am trying to do a grouping and count on city of the ordered list I have.

I have an ordered list of nearest points to my coordinates(110.1862202 1.6031959).

Now I want to group it by cities and count the number of items in each cities.
However, the format is correct but somehow it has lost its ordering. I would like the cities are ordered nearest to my coordinate. The whole point is to get the nearest city but now its not ordered nearest.

query problem group and count subquery

```
  scope :nearestcitysubquery, -> () {
    from(Treasure.order("ST_Distance(treasures.location_point, 
         ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(110.1862202 1.6031959)'))"),
         "subquery_treasure_nearest").group("city").count
  }
```

actual outcome

```
=> {"Kuala Lumpur"=>1, "null"=>1, "Sungai Besar"=>1, "Sungai Udang"=>1, "Kuching"=>1}
```

**expected outcome**

```
=> {"Kuching"=>1, "Sungai Besar"=>1, "Sungai Udang"=>1, "Kuala Lumpur"=>1, "null"=>1}
```

My ordering query works correctly

```
Treasure.order("ST_Distance(treasures.location_point, 
         ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(110.1862202 1.6031959)'))")
```

result of the ordering (which is correct)

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Treasure id: 5, user_id: 1, treasure_name: "Kucing", treasure_image: nil, description: "Kucing", hint: nil, location: "Jalan Ke Puncak Serapi", created_at: "2016-01-08 03:46:40", updated_at: "2016-01-08 03:46:40", treasure_id: "TRKKY", location_point: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3fe9942b71c8 "POINT (110.18 1.6)">, city: "Kuching", state: "Sarawak", country: "Malaysia", difficulty: 2, google_place_id: "ChIJZf_iRaYF-zERMH5qt30cJJw", size: 2>, #<Treasure id: 4, user_id: 1, treasure_name: "Lori", treasure_image: nil, description: "Lori", hint: nil, location: "Jalan Samsudin", created_at: "2016-01-08 03:45:26", updated_at: "2016-01-08 03:45:26", treasure_id: "T3UKD", location_point: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3fe9942bbd68 "POINT (102.14 2.27)">, city: "Sungai Udang", state: "Melaka", country: "Malaysia", difficulty: 2, google_place_id: "ChIJq6_zCZX50TERBdlr6V1CMDg", size: 2>, #<Treasure id: 3, user_id: 1, treasure_name: "Kapal", treasure_image: nil, description: "Kapal", hint: nil, location: "Unnamed Road", created_at: "2016-01-07 09:21:07", updated_at: "2016-01-07 09:21:07", treasure_id: "T3XQR", location_point: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3fe9942ba29c "POINT (101.76 3.5)">, city: "null", state: "Selangor", country: "Malaysia", difficulty: 2, google_place_id: "ChIJWU_xuCoTzDERsigXByaXof4", size: 3>, #<Treasure id: 1, user_id: 1, treasure_name: "Kelapa", treasure_image: nil, description: "Food", hint: nil, location: "Jalan Kiara 3", created_at: "2016-01-07 06:08:56", updated_at: "2016-01-07 06:08:56", treasure_id: "TJKQL", location_point: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3fe9943647d8 "POINT (101.65 3.17)">, city: "Kuala Lumpur", state: "Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur", country: "Malaysia", difficulty: 2, google_place_id: "ChIJ8fBgm-1IzDERPHAF2dYtWTc", size: 2>, #<Treasure id: 2, user_id: 1, treasure_name: "Pulau", treasure_image: nil, description: "Pulau", hint: nil, location: "Jalan Parit 4 Barat", created_at: "2016-01-07 09:20:47", updated_at: "2016-01-07 09:20:47", treasure_id: "TO1BR", location_point: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x3fe9942bd744 "POINT (101.0 3.7)">, city: "Sungai Besar", state: "Selangor", country: "Malaysia", difficulty: 2, google_place_id: "ChIJAfwEx2lgyzERU_zVy8TqaW0", size: 3>]>
```

NOTE: I was told subquery does not order, probably an outer join may work. How to create such a query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a few things going on here which are preventing your ordering from working.

- First, like you mentioned, any `ORDER` clause in a subquery -- which is what your location query is in -- is going to be irrelevant for the order of the final result set.
- Secondly, your `GROUP BY city` clause makes it logically impossible to order your results unambiguously. Suppose you have treasure A in city X, distance=10, treasure B in city Y, distance=15, and treasure C in city X, distance=20. Would City X come first or last in your results?

  However, I think it's reasonable to assume all cities will contain treasures in roughly a similar area, so it's reasonable to order by the closest treasure. So we can handle that problem.
- Lastly, Rails' `group().count` currently outputs a hash of values to counts. That API is probably fairly new and likely to change (hashes really shouldn't be ordered, in my opinion, and the format isn't very extensible). So relying on it might be a bad idea. But, from my testing, it *does* spit out results in the requested order.

In short, what we need to do is move the `order` to the **top level** of your query. To do that, the order clause needs to use an aggregate function (I'll pick MIN, to order by the nearest treasure), and we can drop the fancy `.from` code:

```
# I'm assuming this is on the Treasure model
scope :nearestcitysubquery, -> () {
  group('city')
    .order("MIN(ST_Distance(treasures.location_point, 
       ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(110.1862202 1.6031959)')))")
    .count
}
```

Comment: thanks Robert Nubel, will verify you technique. by the way, where can I put .limit() for limiting the number of nearest items (for example just 30). thanks.

Comment: Before the `.count` ought to do it (i.e. `group(...).order(...).limit(30).count`). Let me know if it doesn't work like you expect.

Comment: Hi @Robert Nubel, the limit is not correct. It limits to number city (in this example 30 city). Can we limit to the number of count ?

Comment: @Axil: I don't follow. The query as-is returns the 30 nearest cities. What are you looking for instead?

Comment: thanks for your response. so for example if .limit(3), it shows 3 cities with the count. The "limit" i am intending to have is to limit the search query result of the number of rows/items. Example: cityA:10, cityB:15, cityC:5  ---> therefore the total is 30 count. So lets say I want to limit it to 30, it means that the count should not exceed 30 for the query count result. Does this make sense to you  ? Thanks a million!

Comment: @Axil: What you want to do is limit by the 30 nearest treasures, then group by city, correct? To do that, you'll need to use a subquery to do the limiting, and then group in the outer query. Something like this ought to do it: https://gist.github.com/rnubel/08794e507e94c5b481cb

Comment: Didnt work, this came up "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "treasures.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Your intepretation of my question is correct - "What you want to do is limit by the 30 nearest treasures, then group by city, correct? "

Comment: @Axil I'm able to run an almost identical query successfully locally. Are you chaining this scope with something else? Try using `.to_sql` on the end of your query expression to debug what's going on.